# Random loading of labels for cities

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have a world map with the states of Germany and Syria and their cities. Right now they load totally randomly as you can see.

[image: Germany partially loaded]
German cities are loaded partially because the labels are missing

[image: Syria is partially loaded]
The Syrian cities are not loaded at all. When I reload it radomly becomes one of the the pictures i posted.

This is my function for calling germany for example.

```
  d3.json("germany.topo.json", function(error, ger){
    if (error) throw error;
    var states = topojson.feature(ger, ger.objects.states_germany),
        cities = topojson.feature(ger, ger.objects.cities_germany);

    g.selectAll(".states")
        .data(states.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "state")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "state " + d.id; })
        .attr("d", path);
    g.append("path")
        .datum(cities)
        .attr("d", path.pointRadius('0.35'))
        .attr("class", "city");

      g.selectAll(".place-label")
          .data(cities.features)
          .enter().append("text")
          .attr("class", "place-label")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });
  });
```

The date ist [here](https://github.com/RitterLean/Timeline_world)

I can partially reproduce this error. Maybe you can take a look and tell me why it is not working properly.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is a result of this call, and the fact that you are repeating it for both the German and Syrian cities:

```
g.selectAll(".place-label")
    .data(cities.features)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "place-label")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });
```

You are messing up your selections by selecting all objects with class "place-label" in different calls to `d3.json`. Instead, try something like the following:

```
// For German cities
g.selectAll(".german-place-label")

// For Syrian cities
g.selectAll(".syrian-place-label")
```

This seems to fix your problem, though you might consider rewriting your code so you only need to add all the cities with one call, instead of two separate, nearly identical calls.